# Slack JSON - Custom Bot Username and Icon

Tags: json, post, slack, slack-api, zapier

I'm looking to send out a Post json request using Zapier's webhook function, together with Slack's incoming webhook set up.

I'm using block kit to develop the message style, and so far that's worked great. However, I'd like my bot to display with a custom username and emoji/icon and I'm having trouble.

Here is the JSON payload I'm trying, based off this tutorial https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#args

The post seems to ignore the first two lines and posts as the standard bot name

```
{
"as_user": false,
"username": "test",
"blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "*78 Varet St #14*\n 2 Bed / $2300 \n <@ben> \n 3rd Deposit This Month"
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "image",
                "image_url": "https://p.sharinpix.com/3/3521a32/YXBwLnNoYXJpbnBpeC5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2I2M2RkZTY4LWZkMDMtNGZlYy04OGUxLWYwZjA0N2E4NjQ3NS90aHVtYm5haWxzL29yaWdpbmFsLWI5MTdlNzAzY2U2LmpwZw/77-varet-st-building.jpg?timestamp=1639154285",
                "alt_text": "cute cat"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to modify the icon and name of your bot ( will be the same throughout the app ), you should be able to do that on `https://api.slack.com/apps/{YOUR_APP_ID}/general?` under the `Display Information` section.

If you want to be able to change it from message to message, you will have to grant your app additional permissions scopes. See https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#authorship

Comment: So, my app has the proper permission (write.customize). I’m looking for the code to include in  messages to be able to utilize that permission and display a custom bot name and icon

Comment: How are you currently trying to post that message?

Comment: I'm attempting to post it via Zapier. It sends out fine, just without the dynamic username